# How do I query User Stories that have Successors in Rally?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to query the WSAPI to find all User Stories with Successors and all User Stories with Predecessors, so I assumed that, like tags, I could use the following query:

```
(Successors != null)
```

Unfortunately, that returns the following error:

```
Could not read: could not read all instances of class com.f4tech.slm.domain.UserStory
```

I'm at a loss; is ({ArrayField} != null) only supported specially for tags? If so, is there a better way to do this in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Tags is a bit of a one-off special case.  The following should work for all filterable collection fields:

Empty collections:

```
(Successors.ObjectID = null)
```

Non-empty collections:

```
(Successors.ObjectID != null)
```

This is documented in the collection section of the WSAPI documentation here:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp

Comment: This works great, but in case anyone else reads this in the future, I ran into a nasty issue.

If you don't specify "order" in the query, the results had a bunch of duplicates, especially toward the end of the list. My guess is that there's something in the ordering that's uniquifying the results.

Comment: nasty.  i think this is an existing defect which hopefully should be fixed soon.  but glad you found a workaround.